# A function to recall column from a csv file

Tags: python, dataframe, filtering

I need to create a function so that would allow me to pull data by columns.For example, the df has column state I want to find all the related airport information for a particular state, say like IL

```
def state(df, state='IL')
```

The csv is loaded into a dataframe already.

I tried:

```
def find_state(df, state='IL')
    df_state = df[df.state =='IL']
    return df_state

find_state(df, state='IL')
```

Comment: You've hard coded `df_state = df[df.state =='IL']` into your function. Change it to take the state variable passed in as the function argument and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You've both given 'IL' as the default for the `state` kwarg, and hard coded "IL" into the function. Replace 'IL' with the argument `state`, and it should work. Like this:

```
def find_state(df, state='IL')
    df_state = df[df.state == state]
    return df_state
```

Comment: God bless your soul